# Lock Document Content for Editing in Document Library

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, permissions

Is it possible to set with permissions or something else, that users can't edit document content, but item metadata still can be changed?

**Scenario is this:**

There is an Order in Excel, that needs to be approved when it is approved, users shouldn't be able to alter document content anymore. But after order has been received, there is `Invoice field`, that needs **filling**.

Is it possible to set this in SharePoint workflow somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that would be to change the document permissions so the users cannot edit it, and use a workflow with an impersonation step published by someone who can edit it to set the Invoice field.  The permissions of the document and it's metadata are not separate.